# After using GParted to give my virtual disk more space, the Ubuntu VM will not boot

Tags: 14.04, grub2, partitioning, virtualbox, windows-8

So I decided to switch from a dualboot setup to running Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit inside of VirtualBox 5.08. My Host OS is Windows 8.1 64-bit. The VM has 2 GB of dedicated memory, from the 8GB on the host.

I first set up the machine to use only a 8 GB VDI, since I just wanted to test it. After deciding to upgrade, I wiped my previous 30 GB Partition and needed to add it to the vdi file. I mostly followed [this](http://derekmolloy.ie/resize-a-virtualbox-disk/#prettyPhoto) guide. In the end, I keep on running into a problem with grub and keep recieving a error while trying to boot.

```
error: attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0' .
```

Here is the step-by-step breakdown of what I have done in my most recent attempt.

First, I used VBoxManage to increase the size of the VDI to 30 Gb.

When I tried to run GParted from a separate VM, it froze while booting, so instead I booted the Ubuntu VM from a ISO, and ran GParted there.

Next, I deleted the swap space partition and the extended partition.

I resized the main partition to be 28 GB.

I rebuilt the extended partition and then the swap partition, with 2 GB.

There was an enormous amount of unallocated space available, around 30 TB (I am using a 128 GB SSD), I believe this was because the VDI file is dynamically allocated, so I ignored the space, but I left it located after every other partition.

I turned off the VM, removed the ISO from the VM, and started it up.

I received an error while booting:

```
error: attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0' .
```

After searching for a solution, I tried:

```
grub rescue> ls
grub rescue> ls(hd0,1)/
grub rescue> set root=(hd0,1)
grub rescue> set prefix=(hd0,1)/boot/grub
grub rescue> insmod normal
```

And received another error

```
error: attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0' .
```

I had no idea what to do here, so I restarted the VM, booting from the Ubuntu ISO again and ran boot repair. [Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12903990/) is the report.

After starting the VM again I run into the same error that occurred before trying the boot repair software. I tried the same solution and received the same error after `grub rescue> insmod normal`

This is the point where I have exhausted my knowledge and the possible solutions I could find online.

I realize that in the amount of time I have dedicated to this project I could have created a new VM and reinstalled all of my software, but I am stuck in a whitewhale situation. The solution has become more important to me than the results.

Any ideas?

(It seems I am only allowed to create two links, I will try to add the image links as a comment on the OP.)

Comment: [Here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2yubB.png) is the link for the GParted Screenshot. And [Here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/oIDo6.png) is the grub screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your disk uses old format from 80's: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record

> The organization of the partition table in the MBR limits the maximum
>   addressable storage space of a disk to 2 TB (2^32 × 512 bytes).

You need to [switch to gpt](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html).

Comment: Well, that ended in tears for me. I simply lack the understanding required to modify the available guides to suit my needs. Thank you for the solution though.